# How can I open xaml designer?

Tags: c++-winrt, xaml-designer, winui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4PZN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6ESi.png)

In this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/creating-a-ui-by-using-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), a user can open designer by right-clicking the xaml file, and choose View Designer. But, there is no command in the tooltip. How can I activate the designer?

I use Blend for Visual Studio, Community 2019, version 16.9 preview 5, for WinUI 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the support page for [WinUI 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/) points out, there is currently

> No XAML Designer support